# jquery and css transition effect change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item").each(function(e){
        $(this).delay(100*e++).fadeTo(700,1)
    })
});
```

html code for each .item

```
<div class="item" style="opacity: 0;transition:none;">
  <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/xjQ1PlIy28PgMz9Vrra1X61kHUe.jpg">
</div>
```

I need to change to fade + bouce in style like popcorntime-online .tv

Comment: There is no "bounce" effect in jQuery, look at jQuery UI for more effects

Comment: hi, thank you for response, some similar effect?

Comment: @GianlucaPenago See this: https://api.jqueryui.com/bounce-effect/